# How to show/hide button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making an app with a dynamic page. I have multiple buttons on my page but all buttons should not be visible at once rather visible one after another in consecutive. I need them to be invisible at first. For instance, the first button should be visible. When I click on that button, the button should disappear and the new button should appear and so forth. What would be the best option for implementing this using ng-show/ng-hide?

Edit--------

As for what I tried to do with them, I tried to do something like this but then I get confused with it all.:

```
<button style="Width: 6em;"  ng-show="show" ng-click="question()">???</button>

<button style="Width: 6em;" ng-hide="hide" ng-click="question1()">???</button>  

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    var darkness = "Darkness";
    $scope.darkness = darkness;


    $scope.question = function () {

        var text = "Nothing but darkness and the pain that radiates through your very being.";
        $scope.text = text;
        $scope.hide = false;
        $scope.show = !show;
    }
});
```

Comment: There are several ways to show/hide/add/remove content from the page, including `ng-hide`/`ng-show`. What have you tried to do w/them? (eg: show the code you tried to use)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a sequences of hide and show.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-hide/ng-show in sequence. Can you please post your code to have better understanding...

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on an application that shows and hides div elements. Hope you can you proceed with the following example.

```
    <div class="container" ng-app="showHideApp" ng-controller="showHideController">
       <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
           <!-- FORM -->
           <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="showMe();">Click me for show</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="hideMe();">Click me for hide</button>
           </div>
       <div class="form-group" ng-show="show">
         <p>I am showing</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
angular.module('showHideApp',[]).controller('showHideController', function($scope){
       $scope.showMe = function(){
         $scope.show=true;
       }
       $scope.hideMe = function(){
         $scope.show=false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: so does that mean putting each button in their own div?  Because that's going to be a lot of divs because I'm going to have a lot of buttons.

Comment: I haven't used a separate div for each button. All the buttons are inside the div of 'form-group'.

Comment: Yeah but the way my game works, most of the buttons can't be visible at the same time.  It wouldn't make since for a choice you make to still be there, it needs to disappear.  And if you aren't to those options yet they shouldn't be available to see just yet either.

Comment: Your code has helped me though, so thank you ^_^.  I no longer need any help.

Comment: My Pleasure @Chiarra