# button enable and disable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Developers, i am new to javascript. i create page include add and unfriend button(disable) each button represent fetch data id from registration page. add button link to prompt box. the data enter in prompt box will insert into database .after that unfriend button will able to click.to avoid customer click add button many time, i put disable option after they click once. now my problem is data can inserted but the button is cannot enable to click.

```
<html>
<script>
  function myFunction(form) {
    var subject = prompt("Please enter Subject that want to study");
    form['add'].value = "request sent";
    form['btn'].disabled = false;
    form['add'].disabled = true;
    if (subject != null) {
      form['subject'].value = subject;
      form.submit();
      return false;


    }
  }

  function unfriend(form) {
    form["add"].disabled = false;
    form["btn"].disabled = false;
    form["add"].value = "Add friend";
    form.submit();
    return true;
  }
</script>

<body>
  <form method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['register_ID'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="subject" name="subject" data-uid=<?php echo $_SESSION[ 'sid'] ;?>/>
    <td><input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(this.form);" name="addfriend" data-type='addfriend' id="add" class="btn" value="add" />
      <input type="submit" value="unfriend" id="btn" onclick="unfriend(this.form);" disabled /> </td>
  </form>
  if(isset($_POST['subject']) and $_POST['id']) { $user_id = $_SESSION['sid']; $friend_id = $_POST['id']; $status = "yes"; $subject=$_POST['subject']; $sql="INSERT INTO friends(user_id,status,subject,friend_id)" ."VALUES('$user_id','yes','$subject','$friend_id')
  "; if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) { $_SESSION['status']="yes"; $_SESSION['friend_id']=$friend_id; $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; } else { } }?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use jquery hide & show function like Ex. `$('#id').show();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling and enabling a html input button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button)

Comment: Please use the search, there are many questions around changing enabled-status/visibility here on SO already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36957886/how-to-show-hide-button